# add rows to a dataset

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is it possible to add rows to a dataset?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

yes.

```
dim row as DataRow 
row = ds.tables(0).NewRow 
' Add Values to Row here 
ds.tables(0).rows.add(row)
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can certainly add rows to the datatables in a dataset.

Check [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034(VS.80).aspx) for a how-to. It covers both strongly typed datasets and untyped datasets.

> ### To add a new record to a typed dataset
>
> Declare a new instance of the typed dataset. In the following example, you declare a new instance of the CustomersRow class, assign it a new row, populate the columns with data, and add the new row to the Customers table's Rows collection:
>
> ```
> Dim newCustomersRow As NorthwindDataSet.CustomersRow
> newCustomersRow = NorthwindDataSet1.Customers.NewCustomersRow()
>
> newCustomersRow.CustomerID = "ALFKI"
> newCustomersRow.CompanyName = "Alfreds Futterkiste"
>
> NorthwindDataSet1.Customers.Rows.Add(newCustomersRow)
> ```
>
> ### To add a record to an untyped dataset
>
> Call the NewRow method of a DataTable to create a new, empty row. This new row inherits its column structure from the data table's DataColumnCollection. The following code creates a new row, populates it with data, and adds it to the table's Rows collection.
>
> ```
> Dim newCustomersRow As DataRow = DataSet1.Tables("Customers").NewRow()
>
> newCustomersRow("CustomerID") = "ALFKI"
> newCustomersRow("CompanyName") = "Alfreds Futterkiste"
>
> DataSet1.Tables("Customers").Rows.Add(newCustomersRow)
> ```

Answer (score 4):

No.  But I suspect you mis-worded your question.

You can add rows to a dataTABLE. A Dataset is made up of DataTables (or is empty).

In order to add rows to a DataTable, you first make the DataRow and then .Add it to the DataTable

Comment: His question is worded perfectly. i have a `DataSet` which is bound to a combobox. But i want the first option of the combobox to be *nothing*. So i need to add an empty row to the `DataSet`. i don't *care* what a `DataSet` is made up of - as long as i can add a row to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can add rows to a datatable, which can be contained in a dataset.  Call the 'Add' function on the "Rows" collection of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding rows to your dataset like this:

```
NewRow = PreviousYear.Tables(0).Rows.Add
       NewRow(0) = Your Value
       NewRow(1) = Your Value
       NewRow(2) = Your Value
       NewRow(3) = Your Value
       NewRow(4) = Your Value
```

This code will add 1 row with 5 columns.

Answer (score 0):

These solutions are good, However if you simply use ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1 then the display will be blank and you don't need a "blank" row in the first place.